# Monitoring Tool for monitoring the health/uptime of my servers in the cluster (windows)

Tags: windows, cluster, network-monitoring

Are there any recommendation on free monitoring tool for windows? We don't need sophisticated tools. We just need to monitor the "health/status" and uptime of our database, load balancer and server.

**Environment:**

Database - MySQL 5.1 
Web Server - Tomcat Apache 
Load balancer - Apache2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can´t remember any free software for windows right now, mut you may check on:

- Big Brother - http://www.bb4.com/
- WhatsUp - http://www.whatsupgold.com/index.aspx

If you can setup a linux machine you have much more options

- Nagios - http://www.nagios.org/
- Icinga - http://www.icinga.org/
- Zenoos - http://www.zenoss.com/
- Zabbix - http://www.zabbix.com/
- OpenNMS - http://www.opennms.org/

---

Just remembered some free tools from SolarWinds (for Windows)

- Network Devices Monitor - http://www.solarwinds.com/products/freetools/network-device-monitor/
- WMI Monitor http://www.solarwinds.com/products/freetools/wmi_monitor/

Comment: Open source Big Brother is called Xymon.

Comment: +1 for Nagios / Icinga. A dedicated monitoring box will prove its weight in gold.

Answer (score 0):

for uptime use pingdom

For server health use serverdensity.

I dont recommend using local software. You need something that is handled for you outside of your network.